# How to order css files in Yii just for a static view?

Tags: php, css, yii

I have a static page in may site controller like page "AboutUs" in Yii framework application.

Now I need to set order some CSS files after the main css files in that static page, No where else.

How to set CSS Files Order in that static page?

**Update**

For example the aboutUs static page load in this address:

```
site.come/index.php/site/page?view=aboutUs
```

Now  i have a static page, named charts which load in this addres:

```
site.come/index.php/site/page?view=charts
```

This page need some `.js` and `.css` files. I register `.js` files, But I need to register `.css` files in custom order.

Comment: can you be more specific, please ?

Comment: Use a separate layout file and specify this using $this->layout = 'my_special_about_us_layout'

Comment: @Alireza Fallah, Update the question ;).

Comment: @crafter How to specify separate layout just for a static page?

Answer (score 2):

When you in view or controller and use `CClientScript::registerCssFile`, there is no param to set order. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCssFile-detail

If you use `CClientScript::registerCssFile` in layout it will be always after your view`s css files.
So if you want to have CSS files in layout that should be always before your view's CSS files, you have two options:

1. Put yout file in main.php (or your layout's main file) before
   `<title>` tag, then other registered CSS files will be always after,
   as they are prepended to the start of `<title>` tag. See
   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#renderHead-detail
2. Second option is to just register your layout's CSS files always
   before view rendering — somewhere in beforeRender in default
   Controller or in another place/helper/component/etc

If you really want to have ordering param, then override clientScript component and add/rewrite registerCssFile method to have some `$order` param. May be there is already exists some component about this.

Comment: Thank you. As i mentioned in update section, i need these `.css` files just in a static page, no where in whole site.

Comment: So just call those registerCssFile from your static page. Did you try this?

Comment: Yes i did so, but the order is my problem. Main css files interference with the static page's css files

Comment: Sooo??? Don't you understand the way to fix it from my answer? But anyway, lets start from concrete examples. Pls describe which concrete css files are in your layout, how they appears there? Put it all in your question. And also how your css from static file get connected.